# Como mudar de cor um item do ListView com base na resposta do "onActivityResult"?

Tags: android, listview

```
lv = new ListView(this);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                                   android.R.id.text1, vetorNomes);
v.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Tenho uma lista de nomes, quando clico no "Pedro" abre uma Activity com um formulário para cadastrá-lo, depois de terminar o cadastro eu dou um finish() na Activity e volto para a lista de nomes, porém eu precisava que o item do Pedro ficasse por exemplo, verde, para saber que já foi cadastrado, estou retornando o nome do Pedro no método "onActivityResult", mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso. Alguém pode dar uma ajuda? Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Há várias formas de fazer isso, terá de dar mais informações nomeadamente em relação ao *adapter*.

Comment: meu adapter recebe dados do banco (uma lista de nomes). Atualizei minha pergunta com o trecho do código.

Comment: Terá de criar o seu próprio *adapter*, de preferência que herde de *CursorAdapter*. Tendo no banco a informação se um nome está ou não cadastrado, é fácil de implementar o que pretende.

Answer (score 1):

Você irá precisar personalizar o adapter eu tenho algo que é aproximadamente o que vc quer segue o código

```
public class AdapterList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private String[] values;
private int mSelectedItem;
private Context context;
public AdapterList(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.layout_navigation_drawer);
    this.values = values;
    this.context = context;
}

public int getmSelectedItem() {
    return mSelectedItem;
}

public void setmSelectedItem(int mSelectedItem) {
    this.mSelectedItem = mSelectedItem;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.values.length;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_navigation_drawer, parent, false);
    TextView  txt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_nav_drawer);
    txt.setText(values[position]);
    if(position == mSelectedItem){
        txt.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        txt.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.red_color));
    }else {
        txt.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.green_color));
    }

   return rowView;
}
```

}

layout_navigation_drawer.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_nav_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="algo"
    android:textColor="@drawable/txt_selected"
    android:textSize="21dp" />
```

dentro do método getView eu tenho um if que verifica se a posição atual é igual a meu item selecionado (mSelectedItem) caso sim eu modifico a cor dessa linha. Veja que eu criei um método para passar a posição que foi clicada no seu caso será a posição do nome que vc realizará o cadastro.

O que vc precisa fazer no onActivityResult é verificar se realmente foi feito o cadastro e passar a posição do nome que foi clicado para realizar o cadastro.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    lv = new ListView(this);
    AdapterList adapter = new AdapterList(this, vetornomes);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //verificar se o cadastro foi feito caso sim o seguinte codigo deve ser adicionado
    adapter.setmSelectedItem(posicao);
    //para que seja atualizado a cor vc deve chamar o seguinte método
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```