# Como alterar a cor de um item ou de todo o Backgroud de um listaView pelo onActivityResult?

Tags: android

Parece que só consigo mudar a cor de um item no `onItemClick()` e a cor do Background completo quando populo o `ListView`.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso? O que eu precisava era clicar em um item da lista da `Activity` A, abrir um formulário na `Activity` B e depois de dar um `finish()` na `Activity` B, mudar de cor o Item da lista da `Activity` A que acabei de preencher o formulário.

Answer (score 0):

Mudar a cor da lista:

```
    ListView lV = null;
    lV = getListView();
    lV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist); // Nome da sua listView
    lV.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); // SUA COR
```

Mudar a cor de uma linha da lista:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    if (highlightedPositions.contains(position)) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); // SUA COR
    }
    return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que respondi uma pergunta semelhante a essa que você fez.

Segue o link:
[Como mudar de cor um item do ListView com base na resposta do "onActivityResult"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81112/como-mudar-de-cor-um-item-do-listview-com-base-na-resposta-do-onactivityresult/81604#81604)