# Como evitar que uma Activity seja criada novamente? É chamá-lá uma única vez?

Tags: android

Estou fazendo um formulário e quando eu termino de preencher o formulário eu preciso mudar a cor do item de um ListView com o nome do formulário que acabei de preencher e deixar a cor lá independente se estou navegando pelo aplicativo e passando pela activity várias vezes, alguém sabe como fazer isso? deixa o onCreate ser chamado apenas uma vez.

Comment: Coloque o seu código na pergunta para a gente entender melhor o problema.

Comment: Acho que não tem muito jeito de conseguir isso... O ideal seria persistir essa cor como um valor no `SharedPreferences` e buscar sempre que precisar.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você tentar alterar o ciclo de vida da `Activity` não terá muito sucesso.

O que você pode fazer é salvar as suas informações em uma variável estática, assim independente da `Activity` ser criada ou não o valor será sempre o mesmo.
Exemplo:

```
public static ArrayAdapter meu_adapter;
```

Assim seu `Adapter` manterá as informações sempre, independente se a `Activity` for destruída e criada.

Caso haja a necessidade de manter os cores apos o fechamento da App recomendo salvar em um banco de dados `SQLite` os registros.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o seguinte, sempre que terminar de preencher o formulário você altera o seu adapter do listView e chama o método `meu_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Eu respondi algo semelhante aqui
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/81604/16057